# Add comment nodes outside root with ruby-libxml

Tags: ruby, xml, libxml2, libxml-ruby, export-to-xml

I am writing an xml exporter in ruby and I am using libxml package for it.
I want to write some comment nodes outside the root element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- comment -->
<root>
 <childnode />
</root>
```

How do I accomplish export to above format?

Sample ruby code to generate the above (without accounting for comment node)

```
doc = XML::Document.new()
rootNode = XML::Node.new('root')
doc.root = rootNode
childNode = XML::Node.new('childnode')
childnode << rootNode
```

Comment: Only operation i can do on the documnet object is setting its root

Comment: However, I can create comment nodes and add them under the root node

Comment: Nokogiri lets you do that. Nokogiri is based on libxml2 too and is a better wrapper than ruby-libxml.

Comment: i tried nokogiri as well. i use builder to export. so within the builder code, we have some how create the comment node. Based on the nokogiri API, i need to get hold of "Document" from the builder object to add a comment, which I wasnt able to figure out.

Comment: Take a look at last part [here](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html)

Comment: i remember ruby throwing a null reference for xml.doc access (xml is anonymous variable), not too sure though. i will check again after the weekend. tyvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up editing the xml string manually to add the comments outside the root node (for both libxml and nokogiri

Answer (score -2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<List type = "" =”00:75:00” =”00:00:05”>

</List>
```

Yes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<List type = "update" >
</List>
```